# Marklogic xquery is not evaluating in html

Tags: marklogic

I have a sample xquery file in c:\dev directory but it is not evaluating in the html page. it returns white blank screen.

I setup http server and index.xqy

```
---Setup http server in Marklogic Admin Gui:
      server name: learnMarkLogic
      root:c:\dev
      port:8030
      module: (file system)
      database: shakespeare


---index.qry-----

xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/html; charset=utf-8"),
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">',
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>shakespeare</title>

  </head>

  <body>

      <p>
         {
          for $x in doc("/shakespeare/plays/a_and_c.xml")
          return <b>{$x/PLAY/TITLE}</b>
         }
      </p>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that the document "/shakespeare/plays/a_and_c.xml" does not exist or does not contain any PLAY/TITLE elements.

Try running the exact code in qconsole (port 8000) to verify.

other possibilities:

If this is not a typo:

```
---index.qry-----
```

Change the extension to one which is defined to corespond to XQuery ( .xqy or .xquery typically), and set your index page in the app server

Also explicitly set the index page to be 'index.xqy'

If still unsuccessful supply the exact URL you are using, a "view source" of the HTML page you are receiving  (or preferably the result of a curl or other means of simply getting the HTTP response)

Varients of 'blank' or 'white' can be hard to diagnose -- so try putting in HTML comments -- they will show as blank but when you do "view source" (or curl) you can see much more then 'white' -- 
In your case - the presence of an empty nested 'b' element  vs none would tell whether or not your for expression found any matches at all vs the contents of the PLAY/TITLE element being blank.

Also -- as written -- you will be getting an improperly used HTML element 'TITLE' if there are matches.

So instead of

```
{ $p/PLAY/TITLE}
```

use

```
{ $p/PLAY/TITLE/string()}
```

The former, if matched, would produce

```
<TITLE>the title string<TITLE>
```

, the later simpy

```
  the title string
```

Your for loop does not likely do what you want,  I suspect you want to loop over all PLAY/TITLE elements.  Your code is looping over all documents name "/shakespeare/plays/a_and_c.xml" of which at most there is 1.

You will still get all the TITLE elements but not nested properly.

try

```
   for $p in doc("/shakespeare/plays/a_and_c.xml")/PLAY/TITLE
   return <b>{$p/string()}</b>
```

Comment: xquery version "1.0-ml";

<p>
     {    
     for $x in fn:doc("/shakespeare/plays/a_and_c.xml")/PLAY/TITLE
         
          return <b>{$x/string()}</b>
     }
    </p>

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what DALDEI has mentioned: you have embedded XPath expressions inside literal XML with a default namespace. That has a side-effect on the default namespace used by XPath too, causing your play titles to not get inserted.

Quickest way out is to use `<b>{$x/*:PLAY/*:TITLE}</b>`.

Alternatively, you could declare an explicit namespace for your data, but I suspect your data is in no-namespace, which makes that a bit tricky.

Another option would be to construct the XML you want to insert outside of the literal XHTML, but you'll have to use element constructors for the `return <b>..` too (`return element {..} {..}`.

You could also give your XHTML a prefixed namespace, but you'd have to apply that prefix to every literal XML tag, which can be cumbersome. And the output would have that prefix too, which does no harm, but consumes unnecessary bytes.

HTH!

Comment: <duh> @HTH I missed the obvious most blatant mistake! default namespaces in explicit constructors.  I so rarely get that right that I tend to always use namespace prefixes for everything if dealing with any namespace xml.  Often a single char like  <x:html><x:h1> etc ...